# Shortened links to PSE posts generated by the "cite" feature don't seem to be added to the Linked tab (as of August 27, 2023)

Tags: bug, status-review, links

I noticed something about the `Linked` tab mechanism that I wanted to bring to attention. In [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/777119/what-is-the-electric-field-around-an-inductor) of mine, I linked to two physics stackexchange posts (please do not edit the links there). I specifically made one hyperlink to be of the form

`https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/442183/kirchhoffs-voltage-law-in-a-general-electromagnetic-field/446505#446505`

and another of the form

`https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/473662`

The second one is a shortened link that comes from the "cite" feature available on the physics and math stackexchange sites. I noticed that when you use the unshortened links, the referenced post is added to the `Linked` tab. However, when you use the shortened link, it fails to be added to the `Linked` tab. I find this an interesting observation.

In case this gets messed up for whatever reason, I'll add a screenshot providing some evidence. You'll have to trust me that the two hyperlinks lead to different pages.

[image]

### Question/Proposal

I presume this was not a conscious choice but simply an oversight (not sure if "bug" is the right term). What do people think of this? Should shortened links by the cite feature be added to the `Linked` tab? Why or why not?

If we agree they should be added to the tab like all other PSE links, is there a way to get the attention of someone higher up to change this?

I am curious to hear what people's thoughts are on this. To be clear, I've noticed this many times before as well. I just decided to bring it up now with a concrete example.

Comment: I tagged this [tag:status-review] since this sounds like a bug someone from SE should look at.

Comment: Related on Mother Meta: [The "linked" feature seems broken for short permalinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64748/the-linked-feature-seems-broken-for-short-permalinks) and [Shortening URL is not listed in the Linked section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296939/shortening-url-is-not-listed-in-the-linked-section); probably other also.

Comment: Ok, that looks like a bug in the cite generator. It produces `URL = {https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/473662}
}` But that's an answer citation, so the URL should be `https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/473662` and if you paste the latter URL (eg, into a comment) then a correct Linked entry is generated.

Comment: More Mother Meta: [Add the ability to cite questions and answers on all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189213/209806)